# Why did the king's son become the next king in hindu scriptures stories?

Tags: scripture, history, kings, story

While reading Bhagwat puran and other books I observed that mostly the king's son is becoming king.

This is surprising. Can we assume that the king's son is the most talented in the whole kingdom, that's why son is becoming king?

King's son can be the most talented but not always. But son is always becoming king and all Raj-purohit are helping to make the king's son the next king.

What can be the reason behind this pattern of the king's son becoming the next king?

Comment: I heard maharaja Bharat made someone else who was more qualified than his sons as king. The thing generally observed is that sons follow their father's occupation. King's son also is raised in such environment from the start and is much more habitual to it. Also, good king's would offcourse make sure that their sons be made qualified for their upcoming position. That's why even princes had to go to gurukuls and live like other student there. Even in vyadha Gita, the butcher talks about just doing his job as his father also used to do it for living and him just following his father.